# SFINAE for true_type and false_type in std::conditional

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, type-traits

What's the best way to make this compile?

```
// Precondition: Dims is either a pointer or std::map.

using T = std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer_v<Dims>,
    std::remove_pointer_t<Dims>,
    typename Dims::mapped_type>;
```

When `Dims` is a pointer, I am getting:

```
error: template argument 3 is invalid
```

How do I make it work in SFINAE manner, when condition is `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct mapped_type{using type=typename T::mapped_type;};
using T = typename std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer_v<Dims>,
                         std::remove_pointer<Dims>,
                         mapped_type<Dims>>::type;
```

we defer the "execution" until after the condition.

Comment: @BenVoigt you're right. I thought `mapped_type<Dims>>::type` was a typo and meant to be `mapped_type<Dims>::type` instead, but looking at the code more closely, I see what it is really doing.

Answer (score 2):

If the passed type (i.e. `Dims`) and the `mapped_type` are always default constructable, you can do something like the following in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_pointer_v

template<typename Type>
auto helper()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<Type>) return std::remove_pointer_t<Type>{};
    else if constexpr (!std::is_pointer_v<Type>) return typename Type::mapped_type {};
}

// helper trait
template<typename Dims>
using ConditionalType_t = decltype(helper<Dims>());
```

**([See a Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nGPE5ETGs))**

---

Or, using partial specialization of the template traits (assuming that you will only pass either a pointer or non-pointer `std::map` type):

```
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_pointer_v

// traits to see passed type is a std::map
template<typename> struct is_std_map final : std::false_type {};
template<typename Key, typename Value, typename... Rest>
struct is_std_map<std::map<Key, Value, Rest...>> final : std::true_type {};

// the partial specialization of helper traits
template<class T, class Enable = void> struct helper_traits final {};

template<typename T>
struct helper_traits<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>>> final {
    using type = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
};

template<typename T>
struct helper_traits<T, std::enable_if_t<is_std_map<T>::value && !std::is_pointer_v<T>>> final {
    using type = typename T::mapped_type;
};

// trait helper
template<typename Type> using ConditionalType_t = typename helper_traits<Type>::type;
```

**([See a Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PaW6cYdzf))**

Comment: In `helper()`, you don't need the 2nd `if constexpr`, a simple `else` will suffice: `template<typename Type> auto helper() { if constexpr (...) return ...; else return ...; }`