# How to make `std::conditional_t` work with recursion?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, type-traits, c++-templates

My use case is as follows:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct peel {
    using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>, typename peel<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::type, T>;
};

template <typename T>
using peel_t = typename peel<T>::type;
```

However if you call this with `peel_t<int *>` you get back the error:

> error: no type named 'type' in 'peel<int>'

The problem seems to be the lack of a terminating condition because `peel` is not specialized to handle the case where there are no more pointers left to remove. But in my head `std::conditional_t` should already be taking care of this.

My question is, is there a way to make `std::conditional_t` work in scenarios where recursion is required (such as this one)? In particular I want the following check to pass:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<peel_t<int **>, int>);
```

Comment: Note that identifiers ending with "_t"  are reserved for the implementation in POSIX.

Comment: @molbdnilo This hasn’t worked with C++ in a *long* time, since the C++ standard has liberally used names that POSIX claims for itself. This question even mentions such a name (`std::remove_pointer_t`).

Comment: Also POSIX is not a part of standard C++. I use these kind of names all the time (in seperate namespaces to be fair)

Comment: its not the traits fault that this recursion is problematic. If `T` is not a pointer you are saying `peel::type` is either `peel::type` or `T`. `T` is selected, but `peel::type` is not a valid alternative

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/68897687/4117728

Comment: actually I dont understand what the underlying issue is you are trying to solve, because the simpler `using type = either_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>,std::remove_pointer_t<T>, T>;` achieves the same and is fine

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I added your proposed changes, plus a clarification.

Comment: onlinegdb.com says: "*error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct peel’*"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai First off, there is no `either_t` in C++. And second, removing `peel` from the 2nd argument will not accomplish the end goal. Your suggestion would make `peel<int **>::type` be `int*` but the OP wants it to be `int` instead, IOW to remove *all* pointers.

Comment: Use partial specialization so the compiler expands the "else" branch only if needed. `template<typename T, typename = typename std::is_pointer<T>::type> struct peel { using type = T; }; template<typename T> struct peel<T, std::true_type> { using type = typename peel<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::type; };`

Comment: @RaymondChen yes, that works. I'm not trying to implement `peel` on its own. I want to implement via the standard library primitive `std::conditional_t` or a similar primitive.

Comment: @Remy `either_t` is what OP used before instead of `std::conditional_t`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`conditional_t` does *not* "take care of this" because it is not like a ternary `?:` that only evaluates the chosen branch. It is instead like a call to a function

```
auto conditional(bool b, auto x, auto y) {
  if(b) return x; else return y;
}
// imagine conditional_t<B, T, F> <=> conditional(B, T, F)
```

Both arguments are evaluated first and you only get to choose one of the results afterwards. If one of the evaluations gives an error, the whole conditional is an error.

Now, for values, even though `b ? f() : g()` is not equivalent to `conditional(b, f(), g())`, it *is* equivalent to `conditional(b, f, g)()`. Reuse this idea of keeping the expressions you want to choose between unevaluated and only calling the right one afterwards. This entails replacing the branches of the conditional with *unevaluated* (i.e. no `::type`) type traits.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct peel : std::conditional<
    std::is_pointer_v<T>,
    peel<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>,
    std::type_identity<T>
>::type {};

template<typename T>
using peel_t = peel<T>::type;
```

This transformation is general and does not require you to reimplement (or even know) the logic in the type traits you are trying to call (in this case `std::remove_pointer`).